# OpenLayers 3 - setBaseLayer Hybrid shows blank map

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, hybrid

this is my first question to the community

My problem is: I cannot start my OpenLayers3 application with Hybrid Layer on by default

I've using OpenLayers 2 until my site started showing blank maps. Due to a LOT of debugging I moved to OL3 with no solution. Using "dirty-free" samples from http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/google-v3-alloverlays.html I realized that the issue presents when I want to set the Hybrid Layer from Google as baseLayer (check the source on examples). If I set Satellite Layer as baseLayer the map is shown perfectly and if once loaded I switch to Hybrid I can see it all. But, again, I cannot start the app with Hybrid on by default.

```
var map;
function init() {
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {allOverlays: true});
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

// the SATELLITE layer has all 22 zoom level, so we add it first to
// become the internal base layer that determines the zoom levels of the
// map.
var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Satellite",
    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 22}
);
var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Physical",
    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, visibility: false}
);
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Streets", // the default
    {numZoomLevels: 20, visibility: false}
);
var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Hybrid",
    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 22, visibility: false}
);

map.addLayers([gsat, gphy, gmap, ghyb]);

// Google.v3 uses EPSG:900913 as projection, so we have to
// transform our coordinates
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(10.2, 48.9).transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    map.getProjectionObject()
), 5);
map.setBaseLayer(ghyb); --> this is the issue
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use OL2 or OL3? You say OL3, but the code is for OL2.

Comment: I was using OL2 and tought the bug was in OL2 so I moved to OL3 and same behavior. the line that sets the Hybrid as a base layer on map loading shows empy map...